# click to subtract 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I want to have some thing like 10 button and each time i should press it should subtract 1. and by reaching zero it should disappear.
html code

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum9' value="9" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum7' value="7" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum4' value="4" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum5' value="5" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum1' value="1" ></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum3' value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum10' value="10" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum8' value="8" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum2' value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum6' value="6" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>


function add() {
    var numArray=["mynum1". "mynum2","mynum3". "mynum4","mynum5". "mynum6","mynum7". "mynum8","mynum9". "mynum10"]
    for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++);
    var num = document.getElementById(numArray[i]).value;
    if(num == '') num = 0;
if(num==1){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    document.getElementById(numArray[i]).value = parseInt(num ,10) - 1;
    }
```

But its not working, what I am doing wrong. Also if you could tell me best javascript practice website

Comment: Can you please define "not working" - what exactly are you having problems with? Is it a syntax error? Please be more specific with regard to what you need help with.

Comment: As it currently stands, your post just looks like you're saying: "Fix my code for me".

Comment: Well you have a `for` loop that does nothing: `for(...);`, dots instead of commas in the array, etc. Are you trying to decrements all the button's values on a click of one button? Also, is the JS within `<script>...</script>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum9' value="9" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum7' value="7" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum4' value="4" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum5' value="5" ></th>
    <th scope="col"><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum1' value="1" ></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum3' value="3" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum10' value="10" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum8' value="8" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum2' value="2" ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="add()" id='mynum6' value="6" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var numArray=["mynum1", "mynum2","mynum3", "mynum4","mynum5", "mynum6","mynum7", "mynum8","mynum9", "mynum10"];
function add() {

    for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++){
    var num = document.getElementById(numArray[i]).value;

if(num == 1){
    document.getElementById(numArray[i]).remove();
    removeA(numArray, numArray[i]);
    if(numArray.length > 0){
    document.getElementById(numArray[i]).value = parseInt(num ,10);
    }
     continue;
    }
document.getElementById(numArray[i]).value = parseInt(num ,10) - 1;
    }
}

function removeA(arr) {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}



</script>
```

hope it helps.